# Why doesn't ln -s tell that it fails when creating a symlink to an existing symlinked directory?

Tags: linux, command, ln

When running (on linux different ubuntu variations):

```
>ln -s dir_1 symlink_dir
>ln -s dir_2 symlink_dir
```

It fails without telling that it fails. But if you do the same thing on a file instead or, add v to the option it does tell you that it fails:

```
>ln -s file_1 symlinkg_file
>ln -s file_2 symlinkg_file
```

**or**

```
>ln -sv dir_1 symlink_dir
>ln -sv dir_2 symlink_dir
```

It fails with the error msg:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link
```

For me this seems to be a very strange behaviour? Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because in the second `ln` it doesn't fail it creates a

```
symlink_dir/dir_2 -> dir_2
```

symbolic link

Do a:

```
ls -l symlink_dir/dir_2
```

And you'll see a (probably broken) symlink there.

That's how `ln` is meant to work if the target is a directory (or a symlink to a directory).

A third `ln` could fail because there's already a `dir_2` inside `symlink_dir` (aka `dir_2`).

Comment: I see. Then the second "ln -sv dir_2 symlink_dir" will then then print the error msg because it is a broken link or something.

Comment: No, a second invocation will print the error because a link at `symlink_dir/dir_2` already exists.

Answer (score 2):

As is desired, specifying `-n` will make `ln` fail in the second command:

```
$ ln -ns realdir symdir
$ ln -ns realdir symdir
ln: creating symbolic link `symdir' to `realdir': File exists
```

Note that `-v` is of course irrelevant to the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can see what happens and achieve desired behavior with `ln` options.
Use this alias for `ln`:

```
alias ln='\ln -vsn'
```

`ln` options:

```
   -v, --verbose
          print name of each linked file
   -s, --symbolic
          make symbolic links instead of hard links
   -n, --no-dereference
          treat destination that is a symlink to a directory as if it were a normal file
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend against putting a `--force` option in *any* alias, there's a reason they're not the default behavior.

Comment: Just `-sn` (or `-ns`) is sufficient to make `ln` fail as desired.